# Howto Redirect 301 strict URL without Parameters?

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

how i can solve this?

**.htaccess**

```
Redirect 301 /item/ /itemlist/
```

yes it works but not perfect!

Check this:

```
domain.com/item/ = domain.com/itemlist/ = OK
domain.com/item/archive/ = domain.com/itemlist/archive/ = OK
domain.com/item/single-item/ = domain.com/itemlist/single-item/ = FAIL
```

last item should be:

```
domain.com/item/single-item/
```

So how i can say only if "/item/" is detect in URL without any other stuff after this?

Comment: This does not make sense. The second and third URL will have to be handled equally. Either by getting redirected or by not getting redirected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Redirect` will match the *front* of a URL.

Use [`RedirectMatch`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_alias.html#redirectmatch) for more precision. It accepts regular expressions.

```
RedirectMatch 301 "^/item/$" /itemlist/
```

… remember that your browser is likely to have cached your previous 301 redirects so it might not appear to be working when you remove the old Redirect directives you have.

Comment: thanks a lot :) works perfect. i tried this regex only with "Redirect" not "RedirectMatch" :D